# How to group a column into sections based on repeating values?

Tags: spotfire

Let's say I have the following column A:

```
------
| A  |
------
| 11 |
------ 
| 0  |
------
| 0  |
------
| 5  |
------
| 0  |
------
| 0  |
------
| 2  |
------
```

What I want to do is create a new column B which identifies a particular group of 0's uniquely. So something like so:

```
------------
| A  |  B  |
------------
| 11 | null|
------------
| 0  | 1   |
------------
| 0  | 1   |
------------
| 5  | null|
------------
| 0  | 2   |
------------
| 0  | 2   |
------------
| 2  | null|
------------
```

The reason I need to do this is because I need to grab the last groups data (in this instance it would be group '2').

Is this possible in Spotfire?

Comment: only for the 0's?

Answer (score 0):

You can break this down a little.

1-  Calculate a column for row id [ROW]

```
RowId()
```

2-  Calculate a column to determine if a given row is in a group of 0s (current row=0 and either previous or next row=0) [IN GROUP?]

```
case  when ([A]=0) and ((First([A]) OVER (Previous([ROW]))=0) or (First([A]) OVER (next([ROW]))=0)) then True ELSE False END
```

3-  Calculate a column which cumulatively counts the rows not in groups [#NotInGroup]

```
Count(If(not [IN GROUP?],1)) OVER (AllPrevious([ROW]))
```

4-  Calculate you [B] column by ranking [#NotInGroup] where [IN GROUP?]=TRUE

```
case  when [IN GROUP?] then DenseRank([#NotInGroup]) end
```